# Cmd Error - Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I developed an application for my diploma, and at some point i have to run a batch file from a java source file. The problem is that every time i try to execute that batch file i get this error: "Not enough storage is available to process this command".

This batch file just runs cvs **log** command. If i run the command directly from cmd, everything goes fine, but if i try to run the batch file which contains this command, i get that error :(

I use this example, for running a batch file:

```
// --------------
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
process.waitFor();
// --------------
```

Where, cmd is a string like this: "cmd /c start \"\" absolute_path_of_batch_file".

Does anyone knows how can i solve this problem? And what it is exactly this error? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe whith the Java application launch in the same time you ran out memory. Try to lower the Java heap with -Xmx. Just a simple guess but it might work if you said that you can lauch the cmd alone.

Comment: alain.janinm: i tried this but it didn't worked. Any other suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry don't get other ideas. it's probably related to windows memory management and I'm more a linux user so hard to tell you... I've retagged you question properly.

Comment: If you are running java with a batch file too, you could try double clicking the jar. /Q = quiet, no echo output. Maybe without start? `cvs log ...`?

Comment: alain.janinm: Thanks anyway! Have a nice day!

Comment: @stormhold Just in case, did you try the fix proposed by Microsoft? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225782 it seems it has helped some people : http://blog.rongabriel.com/2010/03/08/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/ (read the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Running from java will run the command in its own process so it should be exactly as if you ran the command from the command line.  What may be different is the directory you are running the batch file from (or environment variables).  Are there any relative paths in the batch file?

Otherwise, do a `sysout` on that `cmd` string and execute exactly that string in the `cmd` terminal and see if it works.  And also post the exact error.

Comment: Hill: In my batch file there are no relative paths. The batch file is really simple: it gets two input parameters (an directory - where will be executed the cvs log command; and an output file - where will be putted the cvs log command's output). It looks like this: *CD %1 cvs log > %2*. Path of both args is absolute path!

Comment: Hill: 
`To understand better let me show you an example`: [click here](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/1839/57116084.jpg) (i hope that i'm allowed to do this). In the left part of the pic you can see the output generated by executing the batch file, from java source. In the right part of the screen you can see the output directly executing the command in the cmd prompt. **You can see that the output is the same, but it shows that message**.

Comment: Try running your program with `java -Xmx4G <your class>` and see if that works.